# PHP: Split string into array around a wildcard

Tags: php, arrays, string, split, explode

I have a string containing:

```
< a href="/wiki/Bob" title="Bob" >
```

There are ten and more unrelated data in bettween them that i don't need. Basically, I want the title for each one placed in an arrray and they're different. I thought this would be easy, but I can't find out how to do it. Perhaps using explode() and a wildcard, but apparently you can't use a wildcard?

Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT:I forgot to mention that the will change every week form 'Bob' for example to 'Tim'.

Comment: Can you please show an example of some data and how you'd like it split?

Comment: preg_split() might be an alternative; or domdocument as you're trying to extract data from html markup... but showing us an example of what you need might help.

Comment: <th align="center" style="width:10%;"><a href="/wiki/Bob" title="Bob"><img alt="BobSquare.png" src="image" width="48" height="48" /></a><br /><a href="/wiki/Bob" title="Bob" class="mw-redirect">Bob</a> This only 10 times over and instead of Bob there are other names. I just want the naem out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
<?php
$string = '<th align="center" style="width:10%;"><a href="/wiki/Bob" title="Bob"><img alt="BobSquare.png" src="image" width="48" height="48" /></a><br /><a href="/wiki/Bob" title="Bob" class="mw-redirect">Bob</a>';

$title_array = array();
$explode = explode('title="', $string);
unset($title_array[0]);
foreach($title_array as $k => $v)
{
    $explode_string = explode('"', $v);
    $title_array[] = $explode_string[0];
}

print_r($title_array);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bob
    [1] => Bob
)
```